# Git ignore accidentally commited file

Tags: git

I'm working on a project with 4 member of team, everyone have different files config, and we're already using `git update-index --assume-unchanged to/the/file` but the newcomer hasn't noticed to use update-index to the config files and accidentally pushed the file to the repo as in:

```
application/config/database.php
```

And we're working with branches, while we're pulling the file on master it got no warning/something. But the database config file has been changed, and everytime we tried to change branches, this following files always needed to checked out before we change branch.

Is it any method we could ignore this file as if anyone has been changed it? So it wouldn't prompt us to checking it out before we change branch.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: remove it from git using `git rm <file-name>` command and commit change. also since the file is in `.gitignore` it won't be tracked anymore.

Comment: @AbhishekKedia i've used git rm --cached, or is it without --cached? FYI, it's still happening like this after i used and commited git rm --cached.

Comment: `git rm --cached` will remove file from git history only, whereas `git rm` will remove it from both history and current directory. both should solve the given problem. First checkout to the branch(s) where file was pushed. `git rm` it from there and then commit.

Comment: @AbhishekKedia So the file would be removed from the directory too? Is there any other solution?

Comment: if you use `git rm --cached` then it will not be removed from directory.

Comment: That's what i said on my reply comment before, i've already used it but it's still happening.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

1. Remove the file from git : `git rm --cached file`
2. Commit and push the change
3. Add path file in `.gitignore` file on root folder of your repo. This will protect you fron new user to commit the file
4. Commit and push the `.gitignore`file

Documentation : [gitignore](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitignore)

Comment: Thank you, i've noticed i didn't update the gitignore.

Comment: If someone having a problem with above mention steps use `git add -A`  before commit and push the changes.